# How to bind UserProfile to User and another model?

Tags: django

I have created a Company model and a profile model.

**Every User belongs to one company and a company can belong to many users.**

Which of the two is the correct way of modelling it?

```
class Company(models.Model):
    company_name = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    company_code = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    company_email = models.EmailField()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):

        if not self.company_code:
            self.company_code = uuid.uuid1()

        super(Company, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Now the UserProfile is defined like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    # This field is required.
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    # Other fields here
    company = models.ManyToManyField(Company)

    #  !!!! OR  !!!!

    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
```

**Update:**

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    company = models.ForeignKey(Company)

    def create_user_profile(self, instance, created, **kwargs):
        if created:
            UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance)

    post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

I have now added this bit to UserProfile class also added `AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'MyApp.UserProfile'` to the settings.

When I do syncdb I get an error message:

```
>> company = models.ForeignKey(Company)
NameError: name 'Company' is not defined
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `ManyToManyField` would allow a `User` to belong to multiple `Company`s. Based on your spec a `ForeignKey` would be appropriate.

Comment: Sorry I ran into a followup problem, would you know why its not syncing? (see updated question) Thank you

Comment: Err... do you ever import the name?

Comment: Under my models.py? I have the following imports:
import uuid
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db.models.signals import post_save

Comment: I commented out UserProfile and the Syncdb works fine. It must be something with UserProfile that is not right. What could that be? :(

Comment: Oh dear, I didn't realize I had to move Company before UserProfile in models.py. Thanks for the hint.